# How do I connect with my friend in Minecraft Mac

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Me and my friend both live in different countries. My friend lives in Australia and I live in the UK. Can we connect to the same Minecraft (Mac) world without going to a visit?

Answer (score 5):

Yes, but expect a lot of lag because of the distance.

Minecraft worlds are not region specific. You can both connect to the same server or, if one of you creates a server, the other will be able to connect to it.

Answer (score 4):

off course, you have different options :

- join a free server and play right away
- ask to join a server with a whitelist
- build/create your own server
- rent your own server

As Australia and UK are separated by a great distance, you should consider taking a server from a country equidistant from your locations to share and minimize the lag you will have.